# Django Teamplate Error name 'Post_title' is not defined

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-3.0

I'm trying to render index HTML and get post title from database but I'm getting error. I define in views post database but still getting error

name 'Post_title' is not defined

my app/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.shortcuts import reverse
from .models import BlogPost,comments

def index(request):
    Post_list = BlogPost.objects.all()
    template_name = 'front/index.html'
    return render(request, template_name,{Post_title:"Post_title",})

def post_detail(request):
     return render(request, 'front/post_detail.html')
```

my app/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
    path('<int:BlogPost_id>/', views.post_detail, name='Post Detail')
]
```

my project/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from froala_editor import views

urlpatterns = [
     path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
     path('', include('blog.urls')),
     path('froala_editor/', include('froala_editor.urls'))

]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                      document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my index.html template

```
<div class="col-md-8 mt-3 left">
        {% for post in Post_list %}
        <div class="card mb-4">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="card-title">{{ post.Post_title }}</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending the Post_list to the template through context. Send it like this

```
return render(request, template_name, {'Post_list':Post_list})
```